# Sum n, n/2, n/4, ...

Tags: limits, summation

Stackoverflow,
I am trying to train my old analysis knowledge from back in the day and did come to the following question:
Imagine I am on a number line at zero and I would like to go to a number $n$.
I am doing this in the following way:
I go 1 to the left $(-1)$, 2 to the right $(-1+2=1)$, 4 to the left $(1-4=-3)$, 8 to the right $(-3+8=5)$ and so on, until I reach $n$.
Now I would like to know how many natural numbers I have passed this way.
So in fact, the length of my entire "way" from 1 to $n$ was $2n+n+n/2+n/4+n/8$ ...
So in the end its something like the sum of $n/(2^x)$, so it is:
$$\sum_{i=1}^{x} \frac{n}{2^i}.$$
I might got it wrong. If it is correct, how many $n$ do I get in the end?
It looks a little bit lake the geometric series, but I am absolutely unsure.

Comment: So how do you get to $n=2$? When you go to $n=-3$,, you go $0,-1,0,1,0,-1,-2,-3$ ... so is the 'length' of that $7$ ... or $4$ ($4$ different numbers)?

Comment: Why didn't you use MathJax throughout?

Comment: Do you mean $$\sum_{i=1}^{x}{\frac{n}{2^i}}$$?

Comment: @RhysHughes Yes I do, thank you. I correct that now.

Comment: @Bram28 It's the length of 1+2+4+6 = 13, because it's -1+2-4+6 (6 was supposed to be 8, but I stopped as I sad when I cross the number).

Answer (score 1):

The formula for the geometric series is:
$$ \sum_{i=0}^N q^i = \frac{1-q^{N+1}}{1-q}. $$
Applied to your problem,
$$ \sum_{i=1}^x \frac{n}{2^i} =n \sum_{i=0}^x \frac{1}{2^i} -n = n \frac{1-\tfrac{1}{2^{x+1}}}{\tfrac{1}{2}} - n = 2n (\tfrac{1}{2}- 2^{-1-x}) .$$

Comment: Hey, thanks for your comment and answer. You where right about the geometric series. According to your formula: How are n and x relating to each other? I am trying to get an answer where I do have just n as an variable.

Comment: Just to clarify this: I know in the sense of the formula here, n and x do not relate, because n is just something like a constant. But as I mentioned above, the maximum length of one step is in fact 2*n (if you are at -n and the next step 2n takes you to n).